# Ajax does not post to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I receive no errors from either jshint or console for this code. Yet, my ajax content does not post to the intended div(s). The alerts, however, fire:

```
    var recentVar;
    var highlightsVar;
    var test3;
    var test4;

function switcher(divToShow, thisVar, otherVar, url, div){
    $("#site-nav li a").parents().removeClass("nav-active");
        $(div).addClass("nav-active");
        if (otherVar){ $(otherVar).detach();}

        if(typeof thisVar === 'undefined') {
            thisVar = $(divToShow + " ul.top-level").load("assets/includes/" + url, function () {
                alert("I'm new");
            });
        } else {
            $(thisVar).appendTo("#content-listing");
            alert("I'm old");
        }
}

    //Recent
    $("#site-nav .nav1").on("click", function (event) {
    switcher("#recent", "recentVar", "highlightsVar", "recent.php", "#site-nav .nav1");
    event.preventDefault();
    });

    //Highlights
    $("#site-nav .nav2").on("click", function (event) {
    switcher("#highlights", "highlightsVar", "recentVar", "all-web.php", "#site-nav .nav2");
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Upon execution of switcher, thisVar is always going to be a string. It's never going to have typeof undefined. It also LOOKS like you want to pass in an object (due to the declared variables) but... as stated, you're always passing in a string.

Comment: Here is a Fiddle if it's any help. The ajax content should load one at a time, replacing any others that are visible: http://jsfiddle.net/XkzUK/13/

Comment: @GregPettit I would make that an answer.  Based on the code posted, `thisVar` is never `undefined` so the ajax call is never made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with AJAX, but I think your issue is here.

```
$(thisVar)
```

`thisVar` is simply text.  If you check, you will see that `$(thisVar).length` is 0.  This is because you are calling: `$("recentVar")`, which will search for any elements of type `<recentVar></recentVar>`, which clearly there are none.  If your intent is to append that text, you can use `append` or create an element and set the text to `recentVar` and append that.

**EDIT**: Another issue:

```
$(divToShow + "ul.top-level")
```

You need a space here:

```
$(divToShow + " ul.top-level")
```

Otherwise you are trying to match `#recentul.top-level` which is nonsense.

---

Comment: What I am attempting to do is `detach();` the divs so that only one div is shown at a time. I want to use detach(); so I do not have to re-load the content from the database unnecessarily. Is there a better way to do this than what I have done because the method I've tried is obviously not working. Here's a Fiddle if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/XkzUK/13/

Comment: But what is `highlightsVar` and `recentVar`.  These are nothing.

Comment: I was under the impression that to `detach();` the divs I would need to save them in variables. That was my attempt to assign each div a var (`highlightsVar` and `recentVar`), check if they are present, if they are append it to `#content-listing`, if not, assign the var and load the ajax into its respective div.

Comment: Okay, well you are passing a string which contains the name of the variable and using that, not using the variable itself.

Comment: Thanks. That's likely the problem. But how can I pass the variable?

Comment: You should probably start smaller and get individual parts working one at a time.  You have numerous errors, it's a bit tough to fix without re-writing the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

Upon execution of switcher, thisVar is always going to be a string. It's never going to have typeof undefined. It also LOOKS like you want to pass in an object (due to the declared variables) but... as stated, you're always passing in a string.

[per James Montagne's comment]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(typeof thisVar === 'undefined') {
        thisVar = $(divToShow + " ul.top-level").load("assets/includes/" + url, function () {
            alert("I'm new");
        });
    } else {
        $(thisVar).appendTo($("#content-listing"));
        alert("I'm old");
    }
```

Comment: It is helpful to point out what exactly you changed from the original code.

Answer (score 0):

AMAIK, jQuery's `load()` method directly inserts the result into the calling object. Thus the result should get loaded into `$(divToShow + " ul.top-level")` element. Have you checked it?

Comment: Yes, nothing is written to the dom whatsoever as far as the ajax is concerned onclick.

Answer (score 0):

If the current document does not contain an element with an ID of `divToShow + " ul.top-level"` the `.load()` method is not executed.

Try Firebug or such things to track request. Maybe something is wrong with your response.

Comment: Thanks, these elements are included on the page. Here's a fiddle if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/XkzUK/13/